# Maven Parent POM version Declaration in Child Pom Dynamically

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-plugin, parent-pom

Let's say I have multiple projects in which I have not added any dependencies. Instead, I am taking references from a parent pom project.

**Child Project Parent Pom**

```
parent>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-parent-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
```

This child project is referring to Parent Pom having version 1.0, now it is possible that I can a new parent pom project and I define it has version 2.0.

I want some child projects to refer parent pom project Version 1.0 and I want some child projects to refer parent pom project Version 2.0

How do I define
`<version>{some variable}</version>`
dynamically.

Tried adding `<version>${project.parent.version}</version>` but getting error properties in parent definition is prohibited.

Please do help me out. Much needed and stuck!

Comment: You want the version of the parent to come from the parent? That is of course not possible. If a project needs the newer parent, you just update that version number. Or you’re going to have to describe the problem you’re trying to solve in more detail.

Comment: Hello @slindenau , i do not want parent version to come from parent, definitely i will have to declare it somewhere in my child pom. I want to get that version dynamically.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. As the IDEA error indicates you can't use _any_ properties in the `<parent>` definition beside these [predefined ones](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-249179). This is probably because maven needs to resolve the parent first, before it will try to resolve any local properties. If you ignore the error any try a mvn goal anyway, you see that the `${..}` is not resolved. For multi module projects you have [the following option](https://jeanchristophegay.com/en/posts/maven-unique-version-multi-modules-build/), but i don't think that's relevant for you.